# Visual Studio Code for Mac IntelliSense "Console" not working

Tags: mac, visual-studio, c#, intellisense

Microsoft announced today that they have released Visual Studio Code for Mac, Linux, and Windows. I am trying to use IntelliSense for the keyword "Console" but nothing is showing up. I have tried using Ctrl + Space to manually pull up the IntelliSense box but it just says "loading" forever.

here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace chapter3program1
{

    class Program
    { 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly in Mono.

Any ideas on a fix or work around to get this into IntelliSense?

Thank you!